# How can I send data via Bluetooth from C# to a MagicBlue LED?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet

I am writing a .NET application that needs to send Bluetooth packages to a MagicBlue LED. In other words, I would like to create a .NET application similar to it's Android one: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/led-magic-blue/id992330218?mt=8

Here is a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Q3aQjuiLY0

My Bluetooth Adapter has found the bulb and connected to it, so it is discoverable, also I have it's MAC Address, that is needed for my purpose.

I am using the `InTheHand (32Feet Bluetooth) .NET Library` to communicate.
The bulb needs to receive an array of bytes, in order to execute a command (change the color, power on/off, etc).

```
// I use this Write function to send an array of bytes.
private bool Write(byte[] buffer)
{
    using (var bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var ep = new BluetoothEndPoint(_macAddress, Guid.NewGuid());
            bluetoothClient.Connect(ep);
            var bluetoothStream = bluetoothClient.GetStream();
            if (bluetoothStream != null)
            {
                bluetoothStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                bluetoothStream.Flush();
                bluetoothStream.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { } 
    }
}
```

When I reach to `bluetoothClient.Connect(ep);`, it throws an exception saying that `"the connected party did not properly responded after a period of time..."`.

How can I solve this problem the array of bytes to the bulb?

Comment: is `_macAddress` of type `BluetoothAddress`? how do you construct it? what does passing a random Guid as the service Id do?

Comment: Yes, `_macAddress` is of type BluetoothAddress. 
`_macAddress = new BluetoothAddress(macAddrBytes);`. 

Passing a random Guid, does nothing. The same is when I use the `ClassGuid` found in `DeviceManager/Bluetooth/MyDevice/Details/Property`.


The Property `Driver Description` has value `Bluetooth LE (Low Energy) Device`. And I found few minutes ago that `32Feet` does not support LE devices. Can this represent a problem?

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
var ep = new BluetoothEndPoint(_macAddress, BluetoothService.HandsFree);
```

its will be working fine!